# jQuery: Make specific keycode's acceptable for an input

Tags: javascript, jquery, keycode

How can I make a custom validator for an input which accepts only numbers, backspace and full stop. That's keyCode's 47-59, 8 and 190.

I would image it would be something like:

```
$('input').keyup(function (e) {

     if NOT (e.keyCode == 48 TO 59 && e.keyCode == 8 && e.keyCode == 190) {
          return false;
     }

});
```

I also want to fadeIn and Out an added class on the input. For example **class="red"**
The .red then will have a red border to show that it's not possible to type letters.

Something like: `$('input').addClass("red")` with a fadeIn, fadeOut effect.

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this to work:

```
var e = event || evt;
if (e.keyCode > 31 && e.keyCode !== 190 && (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57))
   return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( e.keyCode !== 8 && e.keyCode !== 190 && ( e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 59 ) ) {
   return false;
}
```

You will need the [color plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color) to do the red fade.

```
$( "input" ).animate({
  color: "red"
}, "fast");
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  Too much `||`ing, not enough `&&`- and `()`-ing.

Comment: The `e.keyCode < 48 && e.keyCode > 59` piece will always evaluate to false.  You need to `||` it and wrap it in parentheses.

Comment: Still doesn't work, although I did found the answer on that one